# "Nothing but" usage

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I have seen the phrase "**Nothing but**" used in many places. 
e.g.:

> - Inertia is nothing but the mass of the object.
> - Time is nothing but a line

How did nothing but come into existence?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+nothing+but&oq=define+nothing+but

Comment: *But* has more than one meaning, and one of them is "except", and has been forever. Making "nothing but" just as straightforward a construction as "blue car". Which has been covered in numerous questions before. I am closing this as a duplicate of that particular question because it has links to many more questions still.